# How to create a spreadsheet with an associated script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to programatically create a batch of spreadsheets which contain different data, but all of which contain a button that is associated with a custom backend function.

For example, each spreadsheet should have a button that, when pressed exports the data to another sheet.

Is such a thing possible?

One idea I had was maybe to create a template that includes the button and associated Apps Script and then make a copy of that spreadsheet and fill it with the custom data.

Comment: It is possible to make copies of another spreadsheet which includes it's scripts.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid having the user need to authorize a script every time that they use a new spreadsheet, then I don't think there is any way to avoid that except with an add-on.

Comment: Save yourself loads of hassle and start right.. use an add-on model for distribution

Answer (score 2):

### The [Apps-Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) allows you to programmatically create Apps Script projects with the option of binding them to a Google Sheet

- Convert your project into a Cloud Platform project and [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/enable) Apps Script API for this project
- Give your projects the necessary scopes in the manifest file
- Incorporate Apps Script API into Apps Script with a [Urlfetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) request
- [Create a new Apps Script Project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) with `Method: projects.create` specifying the `parentId`
- [Add contents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent) to the project with `Method: projects.updateContent`. You can store the contents in a variable and thus add the same content to all of your Apps Script projects.

Sample:
JSON file

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

.gs file

```
function createSpreadsheetwithScript() {

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.create('mySpreadsheet');
  var id=ss.getId();
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects";
  var payload = {
    "title": "myAutoCreatedScript",
    "parentId": id
  }
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
     },
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  var scriptId=JSON.parse(response).scriptId;
  var url2="https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"+scriptId+"/content";
 //test content 
  var source="function myFunction() {\n var x=1;\n}";
  var JSONsource="{\"timeZone\":\"America/New_York\",\"exceptionLogging\":\"STACKDRIVER\"}";  
   var payload2 = {
  "files": [
    {
      "name": "this is the gs. file",
      "type": "SERVER_JS",
      "source": source
    },
    {
      "name": "appsscript",
      "type": "JSON",
      "source": JSONsource,
   "updateTime":"2018-03-04T19:49:08.871Z",
    "functionSet":{
      "values":[{"name":"myFunction"}]}
    }
  ]
}

var options2 = {
  "headers": {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
   }, 
  "contentType": "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json",
  "method" : "PUT", 
  "payload": JSON.stringify(payload2)
  }
  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2,options2); 
}
```

> Make sure to [enable the Apps-script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/enable) before using it under https://script.google.com/home/usersettings and that your upadteContent request inclusdes a manifest file

[More samples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/samples/manage)

Answer (score -1):

To write a custom function:

Create or open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.

Select the menu item Tools > Script editor. If you are presented with a welcome screen, click Blank Project on the left to start a new project.

Delete any code in the script editor....

Select the menu item File > Save....
All done!